# Can't display data from firebase because of this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Here i am trying to display all the data to my post page from my firebase, but instead i am getting this type of error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Here is my **Feed.js** where does the work for getting all the data from the firebase.

```js
import { SparklesIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Input from './Input'
import Post from './Post'
import { collection, onSnapshot, orderBy, query } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '@/firebase';

export default function Feed() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState();
    useEffect(
        () => 
            onSnapshot(
                query(collection(db, "posts"), orderBy("timestamp", "desc")), 
                (snapshot) => {
                    setPosts(snapshot.docs);
                }
            ),
        []
    );
  return (
    <div className="xl:ml-[370px] border-1 border-r border-l border-r-gray-200 xl:min-w-[576px] sm:ml-[73px] flex-grow max-x-xl">

        {/* Home nav */}
        <div className="flex items-center py-3 px-3 sticky top-0 z-50 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
            <h2 className="text-lg sm:text-xl font-bold cursor-pointer">Home</h2>
            <div className="hoverEffect flex items-center justify-center px-0 ml-auto w-9 h-9">
                <SparklesIcon className="h-5" />
            </div>
        </div>

        {/* Input */}
        <Input />

        {/* Post */}
        {posts.map((post) => (
            <Post key={post.id} posts={post} />
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

And, I want the all data to display into **Post.js**

Here is the code for **Post.js**

```js
import { ChartBarIcon, ChatIcon, DotsHorizontalIcon, HeartIcon, ShareIcon, TrashIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline'
import Image from 'next/image'
import React from 'react'


export default function Post({ post }) {
  return (
    <div className="flex p-3 cursor-pointer border-b border-gray-200">

        {/* user-img */}
        <Image
            src={post.userImg}
            alt="img-user"
            className="w-11 h-11 rounded-full mr-4 object-cover"
            width="50"
            height="50"
        >
        </Image>

        {/* right-side */}
        <div>
            {/* header */}
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                {/* post-user-info */}
                <div className="flex items-center justify-between space-x-2">
                    <h4 className="font-bold text-[15px] sm:text-[16px] hover:underline">{post?.name}</h4>
                    <span className="text-sm sm:text-[15px] text-gray-500">@{post?.username} &#8226;</span>
                    <span className="text-sm sm:text-[15px] text-gray-500 hover:underline">{post?.timestamp}</span>
                </div>

                {/* dot-icon */}
                <DotsHorizontalIcon className="h-10 hoverEffect w-10 hover:bg-sky-100 hover:text-sky-500 p-2" />
            </div>

            {/* post-text */}
            <p className="text-gray-800 text[15px sm:text-[16px] mb-2">{post?.text}</p>

            {/* post-img */}
            <Image
                src={post?.image}
                width="500"
                height="500"
                alt="post-img"
                className="rounded-2xl mr-2 w-auto"
            >
            </Image>

            {/* icons */}
            <div className="flex justify-between text-gray-500 p-2">
                <ChatIcon className="h-9 w-9 hoverEffect p-2 hover:bg-sky-100 hover:text-sky-500"/>
                <TrashIcon className="h-9 w-9 hoverEffect p-2 hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-red-500"/>
                <HeartIcon className="h-9 w-9 hoverEffect p-2 hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-red-500"/>
                <ShareIcon className="h-9 w-9 hoverEffect p-2 hover:bg-green-100 hover:text-green-500"/>
                <ChartBarIcon className="h-9 w-9 hoverEffect p-2 hover:bg-sky-100 hover:text-sky-500"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error because you aren't passing an `initial state value` into your call to `useState`. When `Feed` first renders, it tries to call `map` against the `post` state variable which is `undefined` until the useEffect can run your `onSnapshot` which updates posts to (hopefully) be an array.

To fix this, update your call to `useState` by passing an empty array as the initial state value:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
```

Also, I don't know if `snapshot.docs` can come back as `undefined|null` but it never hurts to be sure that the posts value is always an array.

Consider adding a [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) (??) to your call to `setPosts` like so:

```
setPosts(snapshot.docs ?? [])
```

I've updated your code snippet to reflect these changes.

Hope this helps!

```
import { SparklesIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Input from './Input'
import Post from './Post'
import { collection, onSnapshot, orderBy, query } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '@/firebase';

export default function Feed() {
    // Pass default value
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    useEffect(
        () => 
            onSnapshot(
                query(collection(db, "posts"), orderBy("timestamp", "desc")), 
                (snapshot) => {
                    setPosts(snapshot.docs ?? []);
                }
            ),
        []
    );
  return (
    <div className="xl:ml-[370px] border-1 border-r border-l border-r-gray-200 xl:min-w-[576px] sm:ml-[73px] flex-grow max-x-xl">

        {/* Home nav */}
        <div className="flex items-center py-3 px-3 sticky top-0 z-50 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
            <h2 className="text-lg sm:text-xl font-bold cursor-pointer">Home</h2>
            <div className="hoverEffect flex items-center justify-center px-0 ml-auto w-9 h-9">
                <SparklesIcon className="h-5" />
            </div>
        </div>

        {/* Input */}
        <Input />

        {/* Post */}
        {posts.map((post) => (
            <Post key={post.id} posts={post} />
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Update: Since you are querying a collection, you have to update the way you `setPosts` as `snapshot.docs` won't work as your posts array.

```
useEffect(
  () => 
    onSnapshot(
      query(collection(db, "posts"), orderBy("timestamp", "desc")), 
      (snapshot) => {
          const userPosts = []
          
          for (const doc of snapshot) {
            userPosts.push(doc.data())
          }

          setPosts(userPosts);
      }
    ),
  []
);
```

Doing this should mean that your code in `Post` component doesn't have to change as far as how you parse values from the `post`.

You can find the official example of this pattern in the [firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection)

Here's the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) for the `for...of` syntax

Comment: is this a correct way to display data to post?  {/* post-text */}
            <p className="text-gray-800 text[15px sm:text-[16px] mb-2">{post?.data()?.text}</p>

Comment: @LeviAckerman Since you are using a collection, you want to update what you're doing in your callback for `OnSnapshot` to build the array of posts before passing it into `setPosts`. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

You're initializing `posts` like this:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState();
```

Since you're not passing any value to `useState`, the initial value of `posts` is `undefined`. And since you then use this as `{posts.map((post) => (` in the rendering code, you get the error message.

The solution is to initialize `posts` with a value that your code can handle, like:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
```

Now `posts` will initially be an empty array, which means you render an empty list instead of getting an error.